# Scikit-learn processing pipeline for text across test, train and validation datasets

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn to build text classifiers. As part of the preprocessing I use a tf-ifd transformer. I have had difficulty when trying to validate a model against an unseen dataset as the vocabulary is different. How can a pipeline be applied to unseen data that needs to be used for prediction at a later time?

Thanks

Comment: If the vocabulary of the unseen data is that different, your training data is probably not representative enough to create a good classification. I'd try to find a larger training set.

Comment: +1 on @jakevdp comment. If you're dealing with unbalanced categories make sure you use stratified sampling so that the percentage of samples of a class is about the same across  train, validation and test set. From there if the vocabulary is different I'd say there's not much you can do except dropping the difference and using only the words that the sets do have in common.

Comment: What happens when a classification model is taken into production? Surely it must be able to deal with unseen words?